# Auto Logout in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, logout, ng-idle

How do I implement auto logout after 30 minutes of idle time using the `ng-idle` module of Angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know much about angularjs, i'm doing a course on it but i'm just getting started. Though I do know someone on github who could help you. I've just included snippets here, but you should check out this site if you want to know more: https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle

Anyway, here it is:

Include angular-idle.js after angular.js. You can install using Bower with this command: bower install --save ng-idle.

Bare bones example:

```
// include the `ngIdle` module
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngIdle']);

app
.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, Idle) {
    $scope.events = [];

    $scope.$on('IdleStart', function() {
        // the user appears to have gone idle
    });

    $scope.$on('IdleWarn', function(e, countdown) {
        // follows after the IdleStart event, but includes a countdown until         the user is considered timed out
        // the countdown arg is the number of seconds remaining until then.
        // you can change the title or display a warning dialog from here.
        // you can let them resume their session by calling Idle.watch()
    });

    $scope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
        // the user has timed out (meaning idleDuration + timeout has passed     without any activity)
        // this is where you'd log them
    });

    $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {
        // the user has come back from AFK and is doing stuff. if you are     warning them, you can use this to hide the dialog
    });

    $scope.$on('Keepalive', function() {
        // do something to keep the user's session alive
    });

 })
.config(function(IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {
   // configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(5); // in seconds
    KeepaliveProvider.interval(2); // in seconds
})
.run(function(Idle){
    // start watching when the app runs. also starts the Keepalive service     by default.
    Idle.watch();
});
```

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it is really helpful. One thing which is not working in my case is, After session expired, browser name is 'Your session has expired'. But after logging in also that name is not changing still it shows Your session has Expired.

Comment: ng-idle is working fine for first timeout. Once timed out, Then we log into application again after that it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it! Need to call Idle.watch() after we login to activate the idle again.

Comment: Hi [user1457957](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1457957/user1457957) could you please give me the detail code to implement ngIdle ?